# Google Maps API v3 api key

Tags: google-maps, cordova, google-maps-api-3

i am writing a cordova app, where i am using Google Maps API V3.
Since this is going to run locally in a web view for each user, i assume that i need to create an api key for google maps api.

I created a new browser key last night, and i put in the referrers all possible urls:
*
127.0.0.1/*
localhost
localhost:7000

but everytime i use it, i get an error saying:
Google has disabled use of the Maps API for this application.

I don't want to use the workaround to simply remove the key, any clues?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have to create an Key for Android instead of a Key for Browsers, then allow your app to use it in google console.

Answer (score 1):

I´not sure if the question is already answered, so this is my solution.
After generate the key and remove all the Referers even "*", Go to Google Maps JavaScript API and enable the api.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try removing all referers, if that doesn't work set referers to the value * as showed in the image below
[image]

Comment: Thanks, i just tried removing all referers, i already tried setting it as *, no luck yet. please note i have other maps api keys for an android app, so my account has no problem serving api keys.

Comment: Is there a fix to this. Can you please share the solution here.