# Cordova google map key api error

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a cross-platform app with *cordova* , but now the *google map* is not working.
I have this error :

```
MissingKeyMapError
```

I try to create new api browser key in google console with "*" authorization url , but still not working. i have this error : RefererNotAllowedMapError 
the window.location.href of my app is :file:///Users/bahri/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/757EE924-9884-44B1-B‌​BF5-04CFF3D68C80/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/820BF808-DFF7-4AB0-8BF8-179D2‌​78E90D5/com.taxiwink.taxiwinkapp.app/www/index.html

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: what is the value of window.location.href for your html?

Comment: this is my href: file:///Users/bahri/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/757EE924-9884-44B1-BBF5-04CFF3D68C80/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/820BF808-DFF7-4AB0-8BF8-179D278E90D5/com.taxiwink.taxiwinkapp.app/www/index.html

Answer (score 4):

As per today (**15 Jul 2020**) the following http referrers allows to show a Google map in a cordova app:

iOS:

```
__file_url__//var/containers/Bundle/Application/*
__file_url__//private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/*
```

(credit to yannisalexiou for having added the last one which works from iOS13)

Android:

```
__file_url__//android_asset/www/index.html#/*
__file_url__//android_asset/www/index.html
```

cordova simulate (eg: simulate ios --target=chrome)

```
127.0.0.1
localhost
```

the referrers go into the Google Console API management (API-Project, credentials, referres) at:

https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials/key/abcxyz?project=api-project-123456

NOTE: developed from the answers here https://github.com/wevote/WeVoteCordova/issues/55

Comment: For iOS 13.1 and newer you need also to add this referrer: `__file_url__//private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/*`

Comment: Thanks yannisalexiou, I've updated the answer with your info for everybody's benefit

Comment: @lui - why won't this work?  does it only support wild card at the end of the string?  `__file_url__//var/containers/Bundle/Application/*/myApp.app/www/index.html#` if we could do this then we could actually lock it down further.

Comment: @rolinger actually it might work even if I fear not... would you give it a try and report back?

Comment: @lui - the documentation says it should work: `https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys#securing_an_api_key` - however I have not been able to get it work when the wild card is in the middle of the path.  Maybe it needs another format?

Answer (score 3):

**MissingKeyMapError    Error**

The script element that loads the API is missing the required authentication parameter. If you are using the standard Maps JavaScript API, you must use a key parameter with a valid API key. If you are a Premium Plan customer, you must use either a client parameter with your client ID or a key parameter with a valid API key.

See the guide to API keys and client IDs.

From :

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#deverrorcodes

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key

Also:

**Registering authorized URLs**

To prevent a third party from using your client ID on their own website, the use of your client ID is restricted to a list of URLs that you specifically authorize.

To see the URLs you have already authorized or to authorize additional URLs:

```
Log in to the Google for Work Support Portal.
In the left-hand menu, click Maps: Manage Client ID.
```

You can add up to 100 URLs at a time, to a total of 3000 URLs. If you require higher limits, please contact support.

**HTTP and HTTPS protocols are considered different URLs.**

```
For example, if https://example.com is authorized, http://example.com is not necessarily authorized. If you'd like to authorize both at once, you may add a domain without using a protocol: example.com/
```

Comment: in my case i have cordova app there is no domaine name ,can i authorize http://localhost/ ?

Comment: http://www.kendrickcoleman.com/index.php/Tech-Blog/phonegap-cordova-geolocation-integration-with-google-maps-javascript-api-v3.html

Comment: Hope one of that link help you, each are for Cordova like application. Give us code otherwise, we will not be able to help more...

Comment: i create new Browser key in google console with "*" with url authorisation and now i have  : Google Maps API error: RefererNotAllowedMapError 


Your site URL to be authorized: file:///Users/bahri/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/757EE924-9884-44B1-BBF5-04CFF3D68C80/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/5355E2DF-C27C-40EB-B15C-6C5C039DEC27/com.taxiwink.taxiwinkapp.app/www/index.html

Comment: Let your url as the beginning and try to activate Javascript url: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23949725/google-maps-api-v3-api-key
Add http url and https url

Answer (score 1):

You should empty the list of authorized HTTP Referers for your key, in the API Console. This should make the map succeed (after a 5-min propagation delay).

Related issues (it's suggested to "star" them to get an update on their resolution):

- [Support API key restrictions with file:// referers](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=9996)
- [Google Maps
  API error: MissingKeyMapError when loading from file://](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=9991)

**UPDATE**

Good news, now you can use file:/ referrers. You can see the following text in the documentation

`file:// referers need a special representation to be added to the Key restriction. The "file:/" part should be replaced with "__file_url__" before being added to the Key restriction. For example, "file://path/to/" should be formatted as "__file_url__/path/to/*". After enabling file:// referers, it is recommended you regularly check your usage, to make sure it matches your expectations`

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key#key-restrictions

Comment: Good thanks for your answer ,google team resolve the probleme ,Now we dont need to specify the key parameter on cordova app

Comment: @bahribenguesmia : usage without a key is [deprecated](https://developers.google.com/maps/pricing-and-plans/standard-plan-2016-update). If it still works, it's because your app is lucky enough to use a grandfathered domain, but usage is limited on whitelisted domains. It's recommended to use a key, and appropriately restrict it to file:// URLs as documented above.

Comment: @NicolasAdrian if I'm not wrong anyone can set up a file referrer like this "__file_url__/path/to/..." and use your API Key.. correct?

Comment: @ValerioGentile correct - hence the recommendation "After enabling file:// referers, it is recommended you regularly check your usage, to make sure it matches your expectations."

Comment: until now the wildcards not supported for file:// referrers which in middle of path like __file_url__//var/containers/Bundle/Application/*/foo.app/www/your.html [https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/80147896](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/80147896). But in iOS devices the app path is not fixed which has GUID likes in the midlle, this causes file referers useless :(